# WFLYJCA0040: failed to invoke operation: WFLYJCA0047: Connection is not valid

Tags: java, db2, jboss7.x

I am using Jboss EAP 7.2. I am connecting with DB2. My application is working fine with Datasource. Today, i have created a new XA Datasource by adding Driver, module, ServerName, DatabaseName and PortNumber. The challenge is, when i try to test connection, i am getting error of Connection is not valid. I can see in JBoss EAP console, it is not showing the connection URL also.
My query is:

- In case of Datasource, i can see the connection URL when i visit my Datasource name but it is not showing in case of XA Datasource
- Also in domail.xml, i can see only 3 xa-dotasource-property (ServerName, DatabaseName and PortNumber)

Comment: Check for more details in the log files and/or web console, show full first exception stack trace in the question. Verify you can connect to the same datasource with same credentials from a different jdbc tool (e.g. a gui like Dbvis, Squirrelsql, ibm data studio etc.) before trying the XA datasource in your app server. You may need to drop and recreate the datasource instead of editing a previously incorrectly done one.

Comment: Seems like something is wrong in your the database connnection setup. Restart JBoss and pay attention to the log file while it's starting up. You should be able to see a database exception there. Get it and paste it in this question.